# Symbol for set of strictly positive real numbers?

Tags: real-numbers

Is there any standard symbol for the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R} : x > 0\}$?

I think $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ usually includes zero. Some sources say I should use $\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$ but it looks slightly bizarre to me.

Suggestions?

Comment: I've seen $\mathbb R_{++} $ for the positive real numbers.

Answer (score 9):

$\mathbb{R}_{\ge a}$ is VERY standard for $[a,+\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_{> a}$ for $(a,+\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$

This is a very obvious "There is no other sensible interpretation" convetion, if I give you $\mathbb{R}_{\le -5}$ you know immediately I mean $(-\infty,-5]$

I have seen $\mathbb{R}^+$ used - this follows the $\mathbb{N}^+=\{1,2,\cdots\}$ convention but I don't like this because it isn't as obvious.

Oh to answer your question, strictly positive reals: $$\mathbb{R}_{>0}=(0,\infty)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|x>0\}$$

Answer (score 7):

There is no one single universal standard symbol recognised and used by everyone. Something like $\mathbb{R}^{>0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is clear enough (I have seen people use both); $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ makes sense but I've never seen anyone use it.

Comment: $\Bbb{R}^*_+$ is used in french books and francophone countries. It's the set of invertible positive real numbers

Answer (score 6):

Well, why don't you give $(0,+\infty)$ a chance? Anyway, positive numbers are different from non-negative numbers: therefore I'd guess that $\mathbb{R}^{+} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x>0\}$, and $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 0\} = \mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\}$.
But many people prefer to include zero for mere convenience, so that it is improbable to reach a universal agreement.

Comment: $(0,+\infty)$ is denoted $]0;~+\infty[$ in a lot of countries. It makes more sense.

Comment: @metacompactness I've always hated reversed brackets. To me $($ means open, $[$ means closed. By the way, here in Italy many colleagues follow your notation, but I learned analysis from Rudin's books.

Comment: @Siminore The notation $(a,b)$ is inconsistent with geometric notation. For instance, $[AB]$ means the segment  including $A$ and $B$; $]AB[=[AB]-\{A;~B\}$ whereas $(AB)$ is a line and not a segment.

Comment: @metacompactness never seen your notation. For me a segment is $\overline{AB}$. But wait, I am an analyst, I write $[u,v]$ for any segment in any normed space! :-)

Comment: How do you distinguish between: (1) the segment $[AB]$ including its endpoints, (2) the segment $[AB[=[AB]-\{B\}$, (3) the segment $]AB]=[AB]-\{A\}$, (4) the segment $]AB[=[AB]-\{A;~B\}$, (5) the line $(AB)$ and the rays (half-lines) $[AB)$, $]AB)$, $(AB]$, $(AB[$?

Comment: @metacompactness I never felt such a need in my life. If it should happen, I'd clarify by words. I mean, if you are an analyst, you use intervals every minute and never use segments. I suspect that the opposite thing happens if you are a geometer.

Comment: @Siminore It happens a lot in geometry exercises. For example let $ABC$ be a direct right triangle at $A$ (that is $\left(\overrightarrow{AB},\overrightarrow{AC}\right)=90^\circ$), What is the geometric locus of the points $M$ such that $\left(\overrightarrow{AM},\overrightarrow{AB}\right)=-90^\circ$? It's the half-line $\textbf{]AC)}$.